# Limit the number of results for autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I'm using React JS and I've created an autocomplete component that returns a list of results.
Here's my code for the autocomplete :

```
const [pokedexMatch, setPokedexMatch] = useState([]);

const searchPokedex = (text) => {
  if (!text) {
    setPokedexMatch([]);
  } else {
    let matches = pokedex.filter((pokedex) => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`, "gi");
      return pokedex?.name?.match(regex);
    });
    setPokedexMatch(matches);
  }
};
```

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dust-tx51n5?file=/src/App.js:560-850) with some dummy text below. As you can see, when you type a single letter it returns a lot of results and move the text below the results.
What I'd like to do is limit the number of results to 5 and make the list of results go above the text (I guess that I should use absolute positioning but I'd like to know if there is another method without absolute positioning) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit your results to 5, use simple Javascript!

```
setPokedexMatch(matches.slice(0, 5));
```

For the positioning part of your question, you're on the right track - you can use absolute positioning of a div with a white background to make the results appear to be "above" the text.

EDIT: I've updated your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-pine-86mp28?file=/src/App.js) and made some very minor changes.

- When you map over an array, make sure you include a `key` prop. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).
- I added the `slice` method to limit your results to 5
- I added a simple `above` class to the parent `<ul />` element to make the results appear "above" the text. This is just one way to accomplish this, I'll leave it to you to style it better if you'd like.

Comment: Thx for the answer and the modifications. So there is no other methods than using absolute positioning ?